# Express router print error

Tags: node.js, express

I have this router with Express.js:

```
router.post("/last-update", function(req, res) {
  rules[req.body.route].last_update = req.body.date;
  log.info("Set Last Update " + route + " " + req.body.date);
  res.send({"statusCode": 200});
});
```

This code will err because `route` on line 3 is undefined. When I send a POST request to `/last-update`, the `node.js` console only logs internal error `500`, without providing stacktrace. Is there a way to enable stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a "catch all" after all your routes are defined. If you already have one just log the error here.

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send('error');
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find where the error gets logged and add this:

```
console.log(err.stack, 'stack');
```

Tip, use [Express Generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) to generate an example application where you will see some examples on how to catch and extract error information:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
```